# What does it mean to perturb the electromagnetic energy with respect to a change in a Lorentz frame?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum

I am perturbing the energy of an electromagnetic field using
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \zeta}
=
\dfrac{1}{\mu}
\boldsymbol{H}\cdot \dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{H}}{\partial \zeta}
+
\dfrac{1}{\epsilon}
\boldsymbol{D}\cdot \dfrac{\partial \boldsymbol{D}}{\partial \zeta}
\end{align}
I know that the electromagnetic field transforms under a Lorentz boost given as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{D}' &=& \gamma \left( \mathbf{D}+\frac{1}{c^2}\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{H} \right)+(1-\gamma )(\mathbf{D}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{v}})\mathbf{\hat{v}} \\
\mathbf{H}' &=& \gamma \left( \mathbf{H}-\mathbf{v}\times \mathbf{D} \right)+(1-\gamma )(\mathbf{H}\cdot \mathbf{\hat{v}})\mathbf{\hat{v}} \\
\end{align}
What does it mean to perturb the electromagnetic energy with respect to a change in a Lorentz frame?

To be more specific I want to calculate the following partial derivative
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial v_x}
\end{align}
but I do not know what its physical meaning represents.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's preventing you?

Comment: @AV23 I am unsure what the physical meaning of this quantity is.

Comment: @linuxfreebird Surely in this case, $v_x$ just takes the place of $\zeta$ in the first expression? You can then plug in the transformed fields $(D'$ and $H')$ and calculate the derivatives to get the derivative of the energy density with respect to the change of velocity $v_x$ of your reference frame?

Comment: (So essentially that quantity $\partial U/\partial v_x$ represents the incremental change in energy density caused by an incremental change in the velocity of the inertial frame)